# How to add icons to the List View Builder list in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, dart-pub, flutter-listview

This is a very basic app which highlights the selected colour on tap.But i want leading icons to the list view. How can i achieve this? If i am adding an icon inside a widget, the same icon is being rendered everywhere. I want unique icons for each list. Please help. Here's my code:

I want to render the icons for each list.

```
 void main() {
      runApp(MyApp());
    }
    
    class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return MaterialApp(
          title: 'Flutter Demo',
          theme: ThemeData(
            primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
          ),
          home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
        );
      }
    }
    
    class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
      MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
      final String title;
    
      @override
      _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
    }
    
    class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
      List<String> texts = ['ME', 'MYSELF', 'I'];
      List<bool> isHighlighted = [true, false, false];
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text('Demo App'),
          ),
          drawer: Drawer(
            child: Center(
              child: Column(children: <Widget>[
                Expanded(
                  child: ListView.builder(
                      itemCount: texts.length,
                      itemBuilder: (_, index) {
                        return GestureDetector(
                          onTap: () {
                            for (int i = 0; i < isHighlighted.length; i++) {
                              setState(() {
                                if (index == i) {
                                  isHighlighted[index] = true;
                                } else {
                                  //the condition to change the highlighted item
                                  isHighlighted[i] = false;
                                }
                              });
                            }
                          },
                          child: Container(
                            color: isHighlighted[index]
                                ? Colors.blueAccent
                                : Colors.white,
                            child: ListTile(
                              //i want to display different items for each list in the leading property.
    
                              title: Text(texts[index]),
                            ),
                          ),
                        );
                      }),
                ),
                Container(
                  child: Text(
                    'this is footer',
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                  ),
                )
              ]),
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

Comment: Please tag your programming language

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  List<ListItem> _items = [
    ListItem(title: 'Me', isSelected: true, icon: Icons.home),
    ListItem(title: 'MYSELF', isSelected: false, icon: Icons.cake),
    ListItem(title: 'I', isSelected: false, icon: Icons.camera),
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Demo App'),
      ),
      drawer: Drawer(
        child: Center(
          child: Column(children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
              child: ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: _items.length,
                  itemBuilder: (_, index) {
                    return GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () {
                        for (int i = 0; i < _items.length; i++) {
                          setState(() {
                            if (index == i) {
                              _items[index].isSelected = true;
                            } else {
                              //the condition to change the highlighted item
                              _items[i].isSelected = false;
                            }
                          });
                        }
                      },
                      child: Container(
                        color: _items[index].isSelected
                            ? Colors.blueAccent
                            : Colors.white,
                        child: ListTile(
                          //i want to display different items for each list in the leading property.
                          leading: Icon(_items[index].icon),
                          title: Text(_items[index].title),
                        ),
                      ),
                    );
                  }),
            ),
            Container(
              child: Text(
                'this is footer',
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
              ),
            )
          ]),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ListItem {
  String title;
  bool isSelected;
  IconData icon;
  ListItem({
    this.title,
    this.isSelected,
    this.icon,
  });
}
```

I made a separate class for each item instead of or having multiple lists.

Comment: Thank you. It worked. Can you please help me with routing. I mean if the user clicks on a particular list tile, it should redirect them to that screen. I am new to flutter and thus i am having trouble figuring this out. Thank you.

Comment: https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/navigation-basics you can refer this

Answer (score 2):

Since you have a list with only 3 items in them as defined by your 2 lists above, if you want an icon that goes for each of the entries in those lists then you should define another list that have those icons and render them depending on the index you are on.

```dart
// (..)
List<String> texts = ['ME', 'MYSELF', 'I'];
List<bool> isHighlighted = [true, false, false];

// add the icons you want to render for each entry here
List<IconData> icons = [Icons.person, Icons.home, Icons.notifications];

// add screens here or use the approach marked as answer above
List<Widget> screens = [PageOne(), PageTwo(), PageThree()];
```

Then in your list tile you can then take the icon based on the index

```dart
// (...)
child: Container(
         color: isHighlighted[index]
                ? Colors.blueAccent
                  : Colors.white,
         child: ListTile(
           //i want to display different items for each list in the leading property.
           leading: Icon(icons[index]),
           title: Text(texts[index]),
           onTap: () =>  Navigator.push(
    context,
    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => screens[index]),
  )
           ),
      ),
```

Comment: Thank you. It worked. Can you please help me with routing. I mean if the user clicks on a particular, it should redirect them to that screen. I am new to flutter and thus i am having trouble figuring this out. Thank you.

Comment: you should probably adapt to @Mr Random answer on using a model class, its a better approach

Comment: Thank you for your help. It means a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Just give the required type in Map or List, whatever you have created.

```
Map<IconData, String> secondSelection = {
  Icons.notification_important: 'Notifications',
  Icons.phone_android_rounded: 'Devices',
  Icons.key: 'Passwords',
  Icons.message: 'Language',
};
```